# Use GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER together in query

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my query I am using rownumber to have a partition on customer id but i want it grouped by emailaddress. Is there a way to do it?

I have two tables, containing the following columns:
Customers:
`EmailAddress,CustomerId`

Orders:
`OrderDate,CustomerId,OrderId,PaymentAmount`

```
select
      t.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(t.OrderID) AS NumOrders,
    SUM(t.PaymentAmount) as Total_Ordered,
    max (case when t.rn = 2 then t.OrderDate end) as previous_date,
    max (case when t.rn = 1 then t.Orderdate end) as last_date
    from
    (
      select 
        c.EmailAddress, 
        o.OrderDate, 
        o.OrderID ,
        o.PaymentAmount,
        row_number() over (partition by c.CustomerID order by OrderDate desc) as rn
      from 
    Customers c
    Join Orders o
    ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
    )t
    group by 
    t.EmailAddress;
```

Note: My data is unique by `EmailAddress` and not by `CustomerID`

Comment: why not partition it by EmailAddress then? what's the point of the row_number in regards to email? You can use `row_number() over (partition by c.CustomerID, c.EmailAddress order by OrderDate desc) as rn` but this would just give you the number 1 for everyone... so maybe you ONLY want `row_number() over (partition by c.EmailAddress order by OrderDate desc) as rn`